# How can I access templates from an imported Django application?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I want to pip install a Django application and be able to access its templates when adding it to the "INSTALLED_APPS" section in Django project's "settings.py" file.

I followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/reusable-apps/) to build a Django app and export it as an installable package, then installed this package into the virtual environment of another Django project.
Everything works fine when I add the app's name in INSTALLED_APPS and when I include the urls of the imported app in the project's urls.py file.

However, when I run the lightweight server of the Django project and try to access one of the imported app's page, I get a "django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist" error.
Why would Django allow to access the urls and views of an imported app, but not its templates or templatetags?

When running the server and sending a request to it for a specific web page, I was expecting to get this web page (located in the templates of the imported app) to load on my browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The MANIFEST.in file was incorrectly setup (it used the wrong names), which led to the templates and static files not being created in the package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).